# Rectangle Marquee Tool

Tags: adobe-photoshop, marquee-tool

I think I've accidentally ticked some option for the Rectangular Marquee tool. If I drag a selection over a part of an object and then hold in Alt to duplicate that selection, the selection snaps to the coloured pixels and removes the pixels that are white (not part of the object).

It's snapping to the pixels in the selection and not including my original selection.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Shaun

[image: Original Selection]

[image: Modified selection]

Comment: Sorry forgot to include the program, it's Adobe photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

Assumption: the "white" in your image isn't really white. It's transparent, most likely a layer with transparency over *another* white layer below it.

---

**Transparent** areas of a selection are not seen as part of the selection when you duplicate. After all, you can't "duplicate" transparency.

This is *standard behavior* for selections. When you drag to duplicate, Photoshop reduces the selection to **only** the *actual* pixels which *can* be duplicated.

If the white area in your selection is *actually* filled with white pixels, then the selection would remain as you set it, because you *can* duplicate white *pixels*.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I've sorted it out.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it's working the way it's intended, assuming the white is either transparent *or* not part of the layer you're working on.

The box drawn with the marquee tool can be moved freely (will show a cursor with a white box w/ dotted border) but this is not manipulating the content within the selection, it's just repositioning the selection itself. As soon as you manipulate the content within selection itself (ie. switching to the move too, or in this case using alt to duplicate it) the marquee will snap to your *actual* selection, excluding empty space.

Sometimes a pixel, low-opacity brush cast or other sort of information on the canvas which is not readily apparent can make it seem like the selection is retaining empty areas.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I've sorted it out.